# Load external script which has document.write using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-dom

I am trying to load cricruns widget using the following script which has `document.write` that will load the widget in the particular container where I have given. How can I achieve this inside `render()` in ReactJS?

`<script src="//www.cricruns.com/system/application/views/widgetBase/wid_300_200_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1j2n2ph/) for more on what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it has document.write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update: ok, I've played around with it a little bit. It works if you just bypass the document.write and add the iframe directly using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I added a working codesandbox below and a code example.

I hope it helps!

https://codesandbox.io/s/z6k1w94z8m

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
  <iframe src="https://www.cricruns.com/widgetbase/wid_300_200_1"; width=250&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=320 " scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:310px; height:250px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  `}} />;
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: after loading the script, i want to get the content inside the script (which has `document.write(...)` that will load widget into that particular container). Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1j2n2ph/)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!